# Perl XML::Twig output as a hash ref

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

How can I get the output of an XML document as hashref using `XML::Twig` similar to what we get through `XML::Simple`'s `XMLout()`?

Comment: nevermind, I got it. simplify() is the one to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer because actual answer is in comments:

Solution to the OP's problem was to use [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm)'s function `simplify`. This turns the parsed twig datastructure into a hash. Deliberately it's similar to `XML::Simple` - but that's probably a bad idea for all the reasons  that using `XML::Simple` is in the first place.

You effectively 'lose data' because hashes don't support duplicate keys (where XML does) and XML doesn't support arrays, where hashes will.

For straightforward data structures, this doesn't matter much. But with `XML::Twig` you often simply don't need to. Iterating with `children` or a `twig_handler` for example.